# $timeout continues to run after page click to other path

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `yo:angular-fullstack` generator to build my website. When a user registers to the site, it will send an activation email with a link. When a user clicks the link, it will show activation successful and a timeout to go to the home page. However, when the timeout has not finished and the user clicks any other link in the page, it jumps to other page with continuing running the timeout. Severally seconds later, the user will be still moved to the home page.

```
$scope.countdown = 10;
$scope.onTimeout = function() {
  $scope.countdown--;
  timer = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);

  if ($scope.countdown === 0) {
    $timeout.cancel(timer);
    $location.path('/');
  }
};
var timer = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);
```

I don't know how to cancel the `timer` when the user clicks other links in this page.

Comment: This is useful information. The same problem occurs in vanilla JavaScript with setTimeout and setInterval. Without clearTimeout and clearInterval, you can end up with lots of background routines that you don't need anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to listen to AngularJS changing the route using the `$locationChangeStart` event:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function () {
    $timeout.cancel(timer);
});
```

That way, when the route changes, the timer is cancelled and the user is not redirected.

Answer (score 2):

```
module.controller("TestController", function($scope, $timeout) {

    var onTimeout = function() {
        // something
    };
    var timer = $timeout(onTimeout, 1000);

    $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
        if (timer) {
            $timeout.cancel(timer);
        }
    });
});
```

you can call it simply when scope is destroyed.

Comment: This is clever too. Didn't think of it this way considering that navigating away from a view will destroy the scope associated with the view. Need to try this one out.

Comment: This is indeed good solution but what if both route uses same controller :p

Comment: @RahilWazir in that case as well if the route is changing this scope will be destroyed.

Comment: @AsheeshKumar Correct!